# Why can't I deploy my jar file on heroku?

Tags: heroku

My version of Heroku is as follows:

```
heroku/7.0.60 darwin-x64 node-v10.2.1
```

When I run:

```
heroku deploy:jar ...
```

I get:

```
 ›   Error: deploy:jar is not a heroku command.
 ›   Perhaps you meant destroy
 ›   Run heroku help for a list of available commands.
```

This seems to contradict the docs:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-executable-jar-files

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Need to install the plugin: "heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy"

Answer (score 6):

I had the same Error, but the docs helped out. Before you can run the deploy command you have to install the java plugin:
`heroku plugins:install java`

Answer (score 5):

It means that you have not installed deploy plugin. So first install the heroku deploy plugin using below command:

```
heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy
```

And then try to deploy the jar. It should work